# QGIS print layout: Pulling the name of the map theme from table

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Currently I have a table of layout names, that are now linked to some layout template to pull the supplement nr, titel of the map and the sourc(for example AGIV, DOV, etc.)

This I have done by just adding some attribute table frames with the filter "Layout" = @layout_name. **Now I want to take this one step further, in the actual table I also have the name of the viewport/theme of the map, normally this was used to keep a record of the theme of the map I should use.**

**So how do I build the expression that the name of the map theme gets pulled from a certain table (in this case the "QGIS Bijlagen Lijst) or rather from a certain layer without geometry?**

Edit: here is the list of name and layer theme, note I have added a fifth variable called scale (schaal). Which is surprise surprise supposed to be the scale of the layout. The formula for the theme should theoretically being used for the scale as well.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with using `[% @layout_name %]` in the print composer directly?

Comment: I am already using Layout_name as title for plan. The theme name and layout name is different. You have four vallue's
Titel,
Layout (this the layout_name for the filter),
Bron And
Theme

Comment: Ah, I see. You could "convert" the table into an expression which uses `CASE WHEN`s to determine which map-theme name to use? Or is there a direct, unique connection between layout name and map theme name?

Comment: Yes kind of with a CASE WHEN. There is not a direct name connection with the theme name.

Comment: Can you provide an exhaustive list of combinations of @layout_name and theme name?

Comment: Erik I have added the list take a look.

Comment: Meh, that would be a lot of `CASE WHEN`s. Basically the expression would simply be `CASE WHEN layout_name LIKE 'X' THEN 'map theme name' WHEN layout_name LIKE 'Y' ...` Though maybe there's a more clever solution.

Comment: I am considering renaming my map theme's to the layout names like you first suggested but even so I would need to make something so the scale can be taken.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression should give you the scale to you layout name.

```
aggregate('table layer', 'max', CASE WHEN @layout_name like "Lay-out" THEN "Schaal" END)
```

`table layer` needs to be replaced with the exact map layer name from the field calculator. You may use this expression as data defined override for your map element.

Comment: Nice solution but it seems only to work half the time for the scale for the other stuff like source and Titel it works for scale it does not.

Comment: "It doesn't work" as in "there is no return" or "the scale doesn't adjust"?

Comment: The scale does not adjust, it just go to random number 602,97...where it gets the number from is unclear. Because the number does not  exist in the table.

Comment: Which field type is your `schaal` field? Integer?

Comment: It is in double.